# No accelerator found - failed to create HAX VM

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I am unable to launch any emulators on Android Studio. When trying to launch an emulator, I get the following error:

```
Failed to create vm ffffffff
Failed to create HAX VM
No accelerator found.
failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x80000000`
```

I have uninstalled Intel HAXM, installed it again, restarted Android studio, tried different system images, and tweaked heap space for the emulator. I have tried different device images, different API levels, and have tried switching emulated performance from auto to both hardware and software to no avail. Nothing I have tried has worked. Here are my emulator's details:

```
Name: Nexus_6P_API_23
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: /Users/mobile/.android/avd/Nexus_6P_API_23.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)
Skin: nexus_6p
SD Card: /Users/mobile/.android/avd/Nexus_6P_API_23.avd/sdcard.img
hw.lcd.density: 560
hw.dPad: no
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.camera.back: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.device.hash2: MD5:9b564b60b1aebee32c73ded9daa1e620
hw.ramSize: 2048
tag.id: google_apis
tag.display: Google APIs
hw.sdCard: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.device.name: Nexus 6P
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.battery: yes
AvdId: Nexus_6P_API_23
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
hw.camera.front: none
hw.gps: yes
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 6P API 23
vm.heapSize: 1028
image.androidVersion.api: 23
runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

Following instructions from Intel's docs, I ran the command `kextstat | grep intel` to verify the HAXM installation and got the following return:

`154    0 0xffffff7f82ae4000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.0.3) <7 5 4 3 1>`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try installing or updating `Intel Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` from `SDK Manager` and also check if `Intel VT-x` is enabled in your `BIOS` settings

Comment: When I uninstalled HAXM originally, I re-installed it through the SDK manager. The current version is 6.0.3. I will check about the Intel VT-x

Comment: Ok. You may also need to update `Repository` then clean and build project

Comment: I followed the link here http://kb.parallels.com/en/5653 to determine whether my VT-x was enabled. This just tells me whether it's supported or not, but it also told me that I would need to check for firmware updates. I did so, found an update, restarted my computer, and tried to load up an emulator and it worked. Not able to confirm whether it was simply the restart that worked or if updating firmware did it. So I will mark this as the accepted solution since it lead me to the right answer.

Comment: I think the update had something to do with fixing the problem. That's awesome :-)

Comment: I am facing the same issue with my Mac, and I have everything updated, and VMX is one of the entry.
but still facing the issue.

Comment: Works for me. Excellent

Comment: i tried updating HAXM and it didn't work, then i uninstall and reinstall HAXM from sdk manager and for some reason it worked.

Comment: Nothing worked for me until *uninstalled* Intel Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and then installed it again.

Answer (score 32):

For those who installed Android Studio without HAXM built in.
You need to install HAXM **manually** after you install it from sdk manager(actually the SDK manager just downloaded it).

Quote from here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

> The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory,
>   under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says
>   "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was
>   downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras"
>   directory to finish installation.

So here is what you need to do:

- Download HAXM installer from `SDK Manager->Android SDK->SDK Tools->HAXM installer`
- Open `<SDK_SRC>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/` and click the .dmg file to start install.

After installed manually, it's better to restart your PC.

Comment: Certainly helped.  And a reboot is definitely necessary, even on a mac.

Comment: Thanks, I found intelhaxm-android.exe in this folder (windows), ran it and it told me that older version is installed. Install new? Ok! And after that emulator is working ok.

Answer (score 21):

Try to uninstall "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" from Android SDK manager, than install it again. That helped for me.

Answer (score 12):

VT-x is enabled by default in all Macs these days.

If you are running Parallels at the same time this will cause the above error. I'm suspect it worked when you rebooted due to Parallels not being run in the background.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Suspending the Parallels VM made it work again.

Comment: Yup, Parallels was the culprit for me too. A suspend is a LOT quicker than a reboot.

Comment: This was my fix as well! Suspended Parallels VM on my Mac.

Answer (score 9):

**Solution A:**

Open SDK MAnager.Install HAX Installer and Android Emulator :

Follow the pic:

[image]

**Solution B:**

Restart your pc and go to BIOS Setting. Enable VT-x or Virtualization or Virtualization Technology from your Advance BIOS setting.
[image]

**Solution C:**

Open your SDK folder and follow the path(**android-sdk-windows\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager**). and double click to **intelhaxm-android.exe**  for update the software.

Or follow those pic:

android-sdk-windows\
[image: Folder 1]

extras\
[image: Folder 2]

intel\
[image: Folder 3]

Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
[image: Folder 4]

Double Click intelhaxm-android.exe
[image: Folder 6]

Answer (score 0):

Solution C work for me:
"Open your SDK folder and follow the path (`android-sdk-windows\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`) and double click to `intelhaxm-android.exe` for update the software".